# Django problem with form using action and not the if method == post in the view

Tags: python, django

So i am trying to add a value to the session dictionary because i wanted to make a cart/checkout for guests.

This is the code in my views.py

```
def productdetail(request, pk):
    Decks = decks.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = order(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           request.session['cart'] = [pk]
    else:
        form = order()

    return render(request, 'shop/single_product.html', {'deck': Decks, 'form': form})
```

And the code in my html

```
<form action="{% url 'productdetailcart' deck.id%}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-round btn-b" type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
```

Now my problem is that without the action in the form tag the session['cart'] in the views.py adds the value in the session which is what i want. But if i have the action to go to that url i only go to the url without adding the pk to the session['cart'] . Its like im forced to choose between going to the page or saving to session.

Comment: This is slightly confusing. You have set up the form to post to `productdetailcart` with the `deck.id`. But you wish to do something conflicting to this, surely you will need to change this and allow the URL to do this.

Comment: @stackdon The form only gets the quantity of the product that are to be bought , the deck id is so i can display the information about that product in the page only for that product

Comment: Sorry maybe i missunderstood your answer do u mean that the action says where i want the form code related with python to be done on ?

Comment: I think you're mixing things up here. Going to the URL _without_ an ID would only be done to add a new record. Otherwise you have an id. Is it your intention that this should work for both addition of new records and maintenance of existing ones?